# Calling an Object Function by name

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I'm trying to call a function in 'this' object by name.
example:

```
class AnObject {
    aFunction() {
        let functionName: string = "anotherFunction"
        let param1: string = "abc"
        let param2: number = 123
        for(var prop in this) {
            if (prop === functionName) {
                console.log(`-------${prop}   ${typeof this[prop]}`)
                Function.apply(this[prop],  ["ABC", "123"] )
            }
        }
        // this[functionName](param1, param2)  // compile error below
    }

    anotherFunction = (paramA: string, paramB: number)  => {
        console.log("called anotherFunction---${paramA} and ${paramB}")
    }
}
```

output:

> found function - anotherFunction   function

with `this[functionName](param1, param2)`  I'm  getting a compile error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AnObject'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AnObject'.ts(7053)

how do I call a function on the current object by name in a string variable?

Comment: `let functionName: keyof AnObject = "anotherFunction"`

Comment: very cool, for better or for was, I loosened type checking and added ```(this as any)[functionName]``` because I'm actually building the functionName from parameters being passed in, thanks.